# How do I parse optional arguments in a bash script if no order is given?

Tags: shell-script, arguments

I'm confused how to include optional arguments/flags when writing a bash script for the following program:

The program requires two arguments:

```
run_program --flag1 <value> --flag2 <value>
```

However, there are several optional flags:

```
run_program --flag1 <value> --flag2 <value> --optflag1 <value> --optflag2 <value> --optflag3 <value> --optflag4 <value> --optflag5 <value>
```

I would like to run the bash script such that it takes user arguments. If users only input two arguments in order, then it would be:

```
#!/bin/sh

run_program --flag1 $1 --flag2 $2
```

But what if any of the optional arguments are included? I would think it would be

```
if [ --optflag1 "$3" ]; then
    run_program --flag1 $1 --flag2 $2 --optflag1 $3
fi
```

But what if $4 is given but not $3?

Comment: `getopts` is what you want. Without that, you could use a loop with a switch statement to detect each flag, optional or not.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash

Comment: @orion With `getopts`, I would need to specify each argument combination? 3 & 4, 3 & 5, 3 & 4 & 5, etc. ?

Comment: No, you just set them if you get them, otherwise it reports it wasn't found, so basically you just "get" each option, in whatever order, and specify them in any order, if at all. But just read the bash man page, it's all there.

Comment: @orion I'm sorry, but I still don't quite understand `getopts`.  Let's say I force users to run the script with all arguments: `run_program.sh VAL VAL FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE` which runs the program as `program --flag1 VAL --flag2 VAL`. If you ran `run_program.sh VAL VAL FALSE 10 FALSE FALSE FALSE`, the program would run as `program --flag1 VAL --flag2 VAL --optflag2 10`. How can you get such behavior with `getopts`?

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand what you want. I thought you want to receive the arguments the same way your `run_program` does (which would make sense). What you are doing is the opposite of `getopts` - you are *giving* options, not receiving them. I'll post the answer below.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang, it sounds like you want your program to read the user's mind to know which arguments go with which option flags just based on the argument position—but then you also want to allow arguments to be omitted.  You can't have both.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[This article](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) shows two different ways - `shift` and `getopts` (and discusses the advantages and disadvantages of the two approaches).

With `shift` your script looks at `$1`, decides what action to take, and then executes `shift`, moving `$2` to `$1`, `$3` to `$2`, etc.

For example:

```
while :; do
    case $1 in
        -a|--flag1) flag1="SET"            
        ;;
        -b|--flag2) flag2="SET"            
        ;;
        -c|--optflag1) optflag1="SET"            
        ;;
        -d|--optflag2) optflag2="SET"            
        ;;
        -e|--optflag3) optflag3="SET"            
        ;;
        *) break
    esac
    shift
done
```

With `getopts` you define the (short) options in the `while` expression:

```
while getopts abcde opt; do
    case $opt in
        a) flag1="SET"
        ;;
        b) flag2="SET"
        ;;
        c) optflag1="SET"
        ;;
        d) optflag2="SET"
        ;;
        e) optflag3="SET"
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Obviously, these are just code-snippets, and I've left out validation - checking that the mandatory args flag1 and flag2 are set, etc.

Which approach you use is to some extent a matter of taste - how portable you want your script to be, whether you can live with short (POSIX) options only or whether you want long (GNU) options, etc.

Comment: I usually do `while (( $# ))` instead of `while :;` and often quit with an error in the `*` case

Comment: this answers the title but not the question.

Comment: @Jasen I looked at this last night and couldn't for the life of me see why. This morning it's much clearer (and I've seen orion's answer now as well). I'll delete this answer later today (I wanted to acknowledge your comment first, and this seemed the easiest way to do it).

Comment: no problem, it's still a good answer, just the question dodged it.

Comment: NB: In case of `set -o nounset` the first solution will error out if no parameter is given. Fix: `case ${1:-} in`

Comment: But, how do you set it to the value of each flag instead of "SET"?

Answer (score 4):

use an array.

```
#!/bin/bash

args=( --flag1 "$1" --flag2 "$2" )
[  "x$3" = xFALSE ] ||  args+=( --optflag1 "$3" )
[  "x$4" = xFALSE ] ||  args+=( --optflag2 "$4" )
[  "x$5" = xFALSE ] ||  args+=( --optflag3 "$5" )
[  "x$6" = xFALSE ] ||  args+=( --optflag4 "$6" )
[  "x$7" = xFALSE ] ||  args+=( --optflag5 "$7" )

program_name "${args[@]}"
```

this will handle arguments with spaces in them correctly.

[edit]  I was using the roughly eqivalent syntax `args=( "${args[@]}" --optflag1 "$3" )` but G-Man suggested a better way.

Comment: You can streamline this a little by saying `args+=( --optflag1 "$3" )`.  You might want to see [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/80216#286350) to our reference work, [Security implications of failing to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/80216), where I discuss this technique (of building a command line in an array by conditionally appending optional arguments).

Comment: @G-Man Thanks, I had not seen that in the documentation, understanding `[@]` I had a sufficient tool to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

In a shell script, arguments are "$1", "$2", "$3", etc. The number of arguments is $#.
If your script doesn't recognize options you can leave out option detection and treat all arguments as operands.
To recognize options use the getopts builtin

Answer (score 0):

If your *input* options are positional (you know at which places they are), and not specified with flags, then what you want is just to build the command line. Just prepare the command arguments for all of them:

```
FLAG1="--flag1 $1"
FLAG2="--flag2 $2"
OPTFLAG1=""
OPTFLAG2=""
OPTFLAG3=""
if [ xFALSE != x"$3" ]; then
   OPTFLAG1="--optflag1 $3"
fi
if [ xFALSE != x"$4" ]; then
   OPTFLAG2="--optflag2 $4"
fi
#the same for other flags

#now just run the program
runprogram $FLAG1 $FLAG2 $OPTFLAG1 $OPTFLAG2 $OPTFLAG3
```

If the parameters are not specified, then the corresonding strings are empty and expand into nothing. Note that in the last line, there are no quotes. That's because you want the shell to split the parameters into words (to give `--flag1` and `$1` as separate arguments to your program). Of course, this will go wrong if your original parameters contain spaces. If you're the one running this, then you can leave it, but if that's a general script, it can have unexpected behaviour if the user inputs something with spaces. To handle that, you'll need to make the code a bit uglier.

The `x` prefix in the `[]` test is there in case `$3` or `$4` is empty. In that case, bash would expand `[ FALSE != $3 ]` into `[ FALSE != ]` which is a syntax error, so another arbitrary character is there to guard against this. This is a very common way, you'll see it in many scripts.

I set `OPTFLAG1` and the rest of them to `""` at the beginning just to be sure (in case they were set to something before), but if they weren't actually declared in the environment, then you don't strictly need to do that.

A couple of additional remarks:

- You could actually just receive the parameters the same way as `runprogram` does: with flags. That's what `John N` is talking about. That's where `getopts` becomes useful.
- Using FALSE for that purpose is a bit unstandard and quite long. Usually, one would use a single character (possibly `-`) to signal an empty value, or just pass an empty string, like `""`, if that's not otherwise a valid value of the parameter. Empty string also makes the test shorter, just use `if [ -n "$3" ]`.
- If there is only one optional flag, or if they are dependent so you can never have OPTFLAG2, but not OPTFLAG1, then you can simply skip the ones you don't want to set. If you use `""` for empty parameters, like suggested above, you can skip all the trailing empties anyway.

This method is pretty much the way options are passed to compilers in Makefiles.

And again - if inputs may contain spaces, it gets ugly.

Comment: No, you don’t want the shell to split the parameters into words. You should always quote all references to shell variables unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing. See [Security implications of failing to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/80216), in case you aren’t familiar with it, and scroll down to [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/80216#286350), where I address precisely this problem (with the same technique [Jasen uses](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/331522/80216#331744)).